# tinyMCE table editing problems

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have two major problems working with TinyMCE. When I use the table editor without having text in the editor I cannot exit the table editing.

1. On hitting "Enter/Return" I only get a newline in the table itself. I also can't click somwhere else in the editor to get the cursor to display outside of the table to enter text under or over the table. I can't tell users to hit the "HTML" Button to enter text there.
2. As soon as I'm IN the table cells, I can hardly edit the width of the whole table... The little squares to drag the table don't appear everytime.....

This can't be hard, I don't know what to google for... been searching for 30 Minutes now....

Using Version 3.2.4.x

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [the latest tinymce version](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download/download.php) (3.3.9.3) because the latest version contains fixes for various problems.

Tables in tinymce haven't been a big issue in my tinymce projects,
but i think a look [at the tinymce table plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3atable) might help. 
This plugin adds table management functionality to TinyMCE (commands and options).

Comment: I'm using tinyMCE in Silverstripe CMS and its' deeply integrated with the CMS so I'm not able to update. The table plugin is integrated. It seems like it's a browser issue. I can click somewhere else in IE e.g.